# Incorporating google maps api into chrome extension/alternative to document.write

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to incorporate google maps api into my chrome extension.  However, I found out that manifest version 2 does not allow `document.write`.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `callback` URL parameter when you load the Maps API, and it won't use `document.write()`. In a normal web page you might do it like this:

```
function initMap() {
    // Create the map object here as usual
}

function loadMapsAPI() {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.src =
        'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js' +
        '?sensor=false&callback=initMap';
    document.body.appendChild( script );
}
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

[Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async)

I don't know how this would interact with a Chrome extension, but that's how it's done in a regular web page.